# Java version discrepancy?

Tags: java, netbeans-7.4

I recently updated from Oracle Java 7 Update 45 to Oracle Java 7 Update 51.  Both the Terminal command (java -version) and the Java Control Panel reflect the updated version, Java Update 51.  However, the following line of code -

```
String ver = System.getProperty("java.version");
```

returns Java 7 Update 45, as it did before the update.  Specifically: **1.7.0_45**

I was expecting it to reflect Java 7 Update 51.

What might be happening here?

Comment: How do you run the program?

Comment: Run your program with full path to java executable.

Comment: There could be another java executable lurking around with which you ran this code.

Comment: Egor: Would that be done in the netbeans.conf file? I'm on a Mac.

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJdkHome

Comment: asgs: I do find both jdk1.7.0_45 and jdk1.7.0_51 folders on my machine.  I was expecting the Oracle update to replace update 45 with update 51.

Comment: Peter:  I will work on that.  Thanks, all.

Comment: Never has a JDK install/update replaced an older version. Never! All of them live together happily forever and ever... unless you uninstall them, one by one.

Comment: Thanks, I now have the result I was first expecting.  I didn't realize that the Java 7 Update 51 left the previous version (Update 45) intact.

Comment: AlfaBravo:  In my case, would deleting Update 45 be as simple as trashing the jdk1.7.0_45.jdk folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the new Java version to the NetBeans Platform Manager, and set it as the default if you wish.